# How to avoids to hit the database when `update_attribute` is executed with "no changed" data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if it is possible to use something like caching or IdentityMapping techniques or, at least, "protect" the database from hitting (for example, if the current object data isn't changed the database should not be hit at all) when running the [`ActiveRecord::Persistence#update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) method *multiple times* in the same controller action and view rendering work flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object.update_attribute(foo, bar) if object.changed?
```

For more infos...

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html

hope this helps,...